# Object.freeze Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Como eu consigo dar um `Object.freeze` em apenas um objeto?

Segue exemplo abaixo onde crio `a`, replico `a` em `b`, freezo o `b`, e tento re-atribuir um valor à `a`. Mas não é mais possível. Porque? Como eu faço Freeze em apenas um objeto?

Obrigado!

```js
let a = { "teste" : [1,2,3] }

// Quero 'b' freezado
const b = a;
Object.freeze(b);

a.teste = [4,5,6]

// 'a' não foi freezado e mesmo assim não consigo alterar o valor dele
console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os valores de um objeto são **"referencias"**, logo você não congela a **"variável"** em si, mas sim o objeto e ao setar ele em outra varivel na verdade você não esta copiando, mas sim **"referenciando"**, por exemplo:

```js
let x = {
    "foo": {
        "bar": 1
    }
};

let y = {
    "baz": x.foo
};

y.baz.bar = 400;

console.log(x);
```

Veja que ao alterar `y.baz.bar` e ao exibir `x` (e não `y`) foi exibido `400`, que foi anteriormente setado no `y`, isso porque você não "clona" os valores, mas na verdade é referenciado, algumas outras linguagens tem comportamento semelhante.

Então o `Object.freeze` vai congelar a referencia, se deseja copiar os valores de um objeto para outro (clonar) use o `Object.assign`, assim:

```
var a = { ... };
var b = Object.assign({}, a);
```

Veja um teste:

```js
let a = { "teste" : [1,2,3] }

// Quero 'b' freezado
const b = Object.assign({}, a);
Object.freeze(b);

a.teste = [4,5,6];

console.log("a:", a);
console.log("b:", b);
```

Comment: Perfeiiito cara, obrigadão!! Salvou minha pele!